# Render ActivityIndicator while calculating data

Tags: react-native

I'm writing some kind of calculator and have issue with rendering ActivityIndicator while my data being processed.

```
 class Calculator extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);

         this.state = {
            ... //input fields state
            isLoadingVisible: false,
            renderData: true
          }
          this.calculationResult = null;
          ... //some bindings
        }

      handleCalculateButtonPressed = () => {
         this.setState({isLoadingVisible: true});

         ... //some calculations and creating of new components
         this.calculationResult = <Result ... //some props with calculated data />
         this.setState({renderData: !this.state.renderData, isLoadingVisible: false});
      }

render() {
        let indicator = (this.state.isLoadingVisible) ? <ActivityIndicator size = "large" /> : null;

        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View>
                 ... //input fields and some text data
                 <Button title = ... onPress = 
                {this.handleCalculateButtonPressed}></Button>
                    </View>
                <View>
                    {indicator}
                    {this.calculationResult}
                </View>
                </ScrollView>

    }
```

I want to render activity indicator after calculate button being pressed and remove it from screen when I finish my calculations. But currently activity indicator never being rendered. I think this issue related to the fact that all js code runs in one thread and therefore we need to finish calculate function first and only then it will re-render the screen, but actually I don't need it anymore.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous and you don't see the `ActivityIndicator` because `isLoadingVisible` is instantly being set to `false` right after you set it to `true`. If you provide your calculation code I'll write up an answer for you. Otherwise, you can try a `.then` block or  a `try``catch` block.  It's good to remember that most processes in React-Native is asynchronous. This will help you debug in the future.

Comment: @Harrison I've just tried to remove isLoadingVisible: false from my code, but after that ActivityIndicator being rendered only after all data being processed.

Comment: okay but when you remove `isLoadingVisible: false` from your code all you're doing is not removing the activity indicator after it's shown. Try a callback function for your `setState` - `this.setState({ isLoadingVisible: true }, function(){ /* your calculation code plus setting isLoadingVisible back to false when the calculation is complete*/ })`

Comment: @Harrison thank you, I've used both your and Nima's answers to make it work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator, Image,    ScrollView, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  isLoadingVisible: false,
  result: 0
}
}

handleCalculateButtonPressed = () => {
this.setState({ isLoadingVisible: true });

setTimeout(()=>{
  this.setState({ isLoadingVisible: false, result: 10 });
},2000)
}

render() {
return (
  <ScrollView>
    <View>
      <Button title="here" onPress={this.handleCalculateButtonPressed}></Button>
    </View>
    {
      this.state.isLoadingVisible ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" /> : <View>
      <Text>{this.state.result}</Text>
    </View>
    }
  </ScrollView>

)
}
}
```

I put timeout only to show you loading is working